# Execute js function after jsf bean returns

Tags: javascript, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm trying to run a javascript function after returning from my bean DownloadIE.

```
<h:commandButton style="display:none" id = "button" onclick="showDownloading();" action="#{DownloadIE.forceLoad}">          
<a4j:support oncomplete="hideDownloading()"></a4j:support>
</h:commandButton>
```

But right now, I can't even seem to get the a4j:support to fire onclick.

```
<a4j:support event="onclick" action="alert('done')"></a4j:support>
```

EDIT#1 Using richfaces3.3.3

Comment: which richfaces version you are using? a4j:support is long gone

Comment: version 3.3.3, the code I'm working with is 10 years old

Comment: This duplicates your second question about oncomplete i h:commandButton

Comment: `action` is for server-side methods, you can't use for JavaScript.

Comment: @Makhiel I'm using action to call Java, I need to know when it returns

Comment: Your sample has JS in it. It returns when it's done, you haven't yet told us what is not working.